# When to create a new repository?

Tags: git, github, conventions

After searching I wasn't able to find an answer and I was wondering: when should a new repository be created? I'm new to version control and learning GitHub, and while there's lots of technical information, I haven't found any about styles and when to create a new repository and how to name it?

For example, if I want to upload code for different sorting algorithms, should they each have their own repository or should they be in the same? If the code is being used in the same project should it be stored in the same repository?

Comment: This question not being about a specific programming/coding problem, it should be in programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're just starting out with GitHub, I'll leave the advanced discussion of submodules out of this.

The general convention is to consider a repository equivalent to a project.  All things that are related to that project should be grouped together in the same repository.

In your case, it all belongs in the same repository.  Two sorting algorithms which can be used?  Ideally you'd have some sort of proxy between the two so that the actual API/contract usage of the sorting algorithms is abstracted away enough from your application so it doesn't matter which one you're using when.

As I mentioned before, you can incorporate submodules which would allow you to have multiple projects in the same repository, but that's an advanced thing that you should do after evaluating your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. In my opinion, you can comfortably hold all your sorting algorithms in one repo. Just make separate sub-folders for each algorithm.

A new repo should only be created for a new project. For instance, if you are working on a 2 different e-commerce sites, don't put them in the same repo unless they have to work together. If you have different projects for different clients, then you might combine the projects in one repo if have a single counterpart on the client side. Otherwise, it would be best to keep them apart.

Think about security (who should access the code), readability (are there overlapping names that could confuse future users) and usage (does one counterpart on the client side need access to ever

Answer (score 0):

To **keep it simple**: It depends on how large your project is.

Giant projects like *Google's Android* have own repositories for nearly everything. They also make use of `git submodule`s which are basically repositories inside repositories.

If you're in a small team usually nothing speaks against using just one repository. But imagine everytime you want to pull changes you would have to wait until 1000 contributions are loaded; This would be very time consuming.

So in your case - I guess -, one repository

1. keeps it as simple as possible
2. is totally enough

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest thinking about what parts of your code need to be committed together.  If changes in one part of your code need to be synchronized with changes in another part of your code, then it will make life easier if you keep those in the same repository whenever possible.  This applies in particular when the dependencies are bidirectional.

If changes in one part of your codebase can happen completely independently from another part of your codebase, then you can feel free to put those parts of your code in different repositories.